# Adding Color Bar to GRIB Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, grib

I can't figure out how to add a color bar to my GRIB plot using the following code:

```
grib='/home/rik/hrrr/afr/vis.t20z.f00.grib2'
grbs=pygrib.open(grib)

lats, lons = grb.latlons()

map_crs = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-100,
                            central_latitude=35,
                            standard_parallels=(30, 60))
data_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(14,12))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=map_crs)
ax.set_extent([-120, -75, 25, 50], data_crs)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))

ax.contourf(lons, lats, grb.values, transform=data_crs)

plt.title('Surface Visibility')

plt.colorbar(grb.values, orientation='vertical')
```

After executing the above code I see the plot with an empty vertical color bar. What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look to cartopy which is specially made for geographical data visualisation. You can also have a look into xarray that is working with matplotlib as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `plt.colorbar()`, the first argument is the matplotlib artist that the colorbar should correspond with--in this case you're colormapping `contourf`, so you should take the return value from this method and pass it, like this:

```
cntr = ax.contourf(lons, lats, grb.values, transform=data_crs)
plt.colorbar(cntr, orientation='vertical')
```